# How to check if a date is between two given date

Tags: vb6

how to check if a date is between two given date in vb Like :

```
If ( BirthDate Between T1 and T2)  Then
    Label5.Caption = " Your Horoscope Sign is LIBRA"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compare it between both T1 and T2. Something like this should work. Keep in mind the years will have to be the same or the comparison will not work, also this comparison includes the endpoints if you do not wish that remove the equals sign, this is also supposing that you are using date objects

```
If (BirthDate >= T1 And BirthDate <= T2) Then
    Label5.Caption = "You're In"
Else
    Label5.Caption = "You're Out"
End If
```